# How to overide "Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml" in custom module?

Tags: magento2, template-override

I am trying to override core template file

```
Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml
```

in custom module, but not sure how to start
Any thoughts please.

i have created  a layout file in `view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_email_items">
            <action method="setEmailItems">
                <argument name="emailItems" xsi:type="string">Emp_Sales::email/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <action method="setOrderTotals">
                <argument name="orderTotals" xsi:type="string">Emp_Sales::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement below code to override template file.

> Step 1: Please create file sales_email_order_items.xml file under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">PackageName_Module::email/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">PackageName_Module::order/totals.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

> Step 2: Please create items.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/

Copy paste all code from core file Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml and edit code now in your custom phtml file according to your requirement.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order) : ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item) : ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
            ->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore())
        && $_order->getGiftMessageId()
    ) : ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
            ->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage) : ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message for this Order')) ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Step 3: Please create totals.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/templates/order/

Copy paste all code from core file Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml and edit code now in your custom phtml file according to your requirement.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 */
?>
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()) : ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false) ?>
    <?php else :?>
    <tr class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?>">
        <th <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLabelProperties() ?> scope="row">
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </th>
        <td <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getValueProperties() ?> data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_total->getLabel()) ?>">
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                <strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: Hello thankyou for the answer,how can i override "Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml" in module ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Could you please approve and upvote this?

Comment: argument name should be unique

Comment: Which argument you are talking about?

Comment: Could please approve my answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Declare in di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" type="Emp\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" />
```

Then create a class

Emp\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items

```
<?php

namespace Emp\Sales\Block\Order\Email;

class Items extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items
{
}
```

**Then Run Following commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile && 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```